# Choosing from a list of names using factory boy integrated with faker

Tags: django-rest-framework, faker, factory-boy

I am trying to use factory.faker to randomly choose from a list of four companies and use them as a traffic source for a list of generated names. I am using the below code:

```
    from django.db import models
    import factory
    import factory.django
    from datetime import datetime
    from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
    from faker import Faker
    from faker.providers import BaseProvider
    import random

    fake = Faker()

    class User(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=128)
        phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=32)
        login_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), blank=True)
        session_duration = models.IntegerField(default = 0, validators=  [
                           MinValueValidator(0),
                           MaxValueValidator(5)
                           ])
        traffic_source = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
        class Meta:
            model = User

        name = factory.Faker('name')
        address = factory.Faker('address')
        phone_number = factory.Faker('phone_number')
        login_date = factory.Faker('date')
        session_duration = factory.Faker('random_int')



        traffic_source = random.choice(['XYZ', 'ABC', '123', '456'])
```

The issue is that for all 200 iterations I perform using the following in the python shell:

```
    for _ in range(200): 
        UserFactory.create()
```

I get the same company for every name, i.e. 'XYZ' for all 200 names.

Am I missing something? I want to get a different company for each of the 200 iterations. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This comes from Python's parsing rules.

#### Why?

When you write this:

```py
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    ...
    traffic_source = random.choice(['XYZ', 'ABC', '123', '456'])
```

Python will execute the following steps:

1. Read the class declaration body;
2. Reach the line `traffic_source = random.choice(['XYZ', 'ABC', '123', '456'])`;
3. Evaluate the call to `random.choice`, which might return `'ABC'`;
4. Once each line of the class body has been read (and its function calls evaluated), create the class:

   ````py
   UserFactory = type(
       name='UserFactory',
       bases=[factory.django.DjangoModelFactory],
       {'traffic_source': 'ABC', ...},
    )```
   ````

As you can see, the call to `random.choice` is performed only **once**, when parsing the class declaration.

This is, basically, the reason for all the `factory.XXX` declarations: they yield an object that will only execute its specific rules when building an instance from the factory.

#### So, what should you do?

Here, you should use:

- Either `factory.Faker` using [Faker's `random_choices` provider](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers/baseprovider.html#faker.providers.BaseProvider.random_choices);
- Or [`factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fuzzy.html#fuzzychoice):

```py
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    ...
    traffic_source = factory.Faker('random_choices', elements=['XYZ', 'ABC', '123', '456'])
    alt_traffic_source = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice(['XYZ', 'ABC', '123', '456'])
```

The main difference between `factory.Faker('random_choices')` and `factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoices` is that `factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoices` supports lazily evaluating generators; this is useful if you want to choose from a queryset:

- `factory.Faker('random_choices', elements=Company.objects.all())` will perform a DB query at import time;
- `factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice(Company.objects.all())` will only query the DB the first time `UserFactory.create()` is called.

Comment: Awesome, yeah, a simple error on my part. I ended up going with the fuzzychoice method and it worked perfectly. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Note: if you want only 1 element I found that Faker `random_element` was what I needed (random_choices returns a list)

Comment: Sadly, factory.fuzzy is now deprecated, and there is no "lazy evaluation" equivalent on Faker (or at least is what i understood from https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/271)

Answer (score 1):

While not truly random, the effect you're looking for when choosing from among a set of pre-existing records can also be achieved by using FactoryBoy's `Iterator`, which can also work with a QuerySet. For example, here I wanted every object to be created by someone different from the set of existing fake users:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
...

# Then, within a factory class, for one of the fields:
created_by = factory.Iterator(get_user_model().objects.all())
```