# Django Factory Boy and Faker always return same value

Tags: django, faker, factory-boy

I'm trying to generate dummy data and I have a selectable field among several options but the same sector is always generated

models.py:

```
SECTOR = (("1", _("Administración y gestión")), ("2", _("Agricultura y ganadería")), ("3", _("Industria alimentaria")), ("4", _("Grandes almacenes")), ("5", _("Comercio")), ("6", _("Construcción e industrias extractivas")), ("7", _("Actividades físico-deportivas")))

class Company(TimeEntity):
  ...
  sector = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Sector"), max_length=20, choices=SECTOR, default=1)
```

factories.py:

```
SECTOR_FACTORY = list(map(lambda x: x[0], app_models.SECTOR))

class CompanyFactory(DjangoModelFactory):

  class Meta:
    model = app_models.Company

  sector = fake.random_choices(elements=SECTOR_FACTORY, length=1)
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is similar to the topics covered in that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62724145/choosing-from-a-list-of-names-using-factory-boy-integrated-with-faker/62728505#62728505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated with the correct code

```
from factory.fuzzy import FuzzyChoice

SECTOR_FACTORY = list(map(lambda x: x[0], app_models.SECTOR))

class CompanyFactory(DjangoModelFactory):

  class Meta:
    model = app_models.Company

  sector = FuzzyChoice(SECTOR_FACTORY)
```