# Random model values inside list subfactory elements

Tags: python, faker, factory-boy

I cannot find an answer to my question. The thing is that I want to generate an User factory model where inside will be a subfactory List with Addresses. Each Addresses element must have different/random values (I mean that each element has non-repeatable unique values).

In my current implementation, all of the elements have the same values (maybe seeding is necessary?)

Actual code:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from factory import Factory, List, Subfactory


class Address(BaseModel):
    Name: str


class User(BaseModel):
    Addresses: list[Address]


class AddressFactory(Factory):
    Name = fake.name()

    class Meta:
        model = Address


class UserFactory(Factory):
    Addresses = List([SubFactory(AddressFactory) for _ in range(3)])

    class Meta:
        model = User
```

Actual output:

```
> UserFactory()
> User(Addresses=[Address(Name='Isa Merkx'), Address(Name='Isa Merkx'), Address(Name='Isa Merkx')])
```

Desired Output:

```
> UserFactory()
> User(Addresses=[Address(Name='Isa Merkx'), Address(Name='John Smith'), Address(Name='Elon Musk')])
```

Comment: Hi! Please include all relevant `import` so that we can play around with your code without hitting `NameError: name 'BaseModel' is not defined`

Comment: @Stef Edited. I've added necessary imports.

Comment: Could you also explain what `Factory` and `Subfactory` are and what the do?

Comment: `Factory` is imported from factory-boy lib and is used to generate factory for specified model in Meta class. Subfactory -> This attribute declaration calls another Factory subclass, selecting the same build strategy and collecting extra kwargs in the process. (from factory boy documentation)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `LazyAttribute` to get a different value each time.

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel
import factory
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker('en_GB') # <-- missing from the original example


class Address(BaseModel):
    Street: str
    HouseNumber: str
    City: str
    Postcode: str


class AddressFactory(factory.Factory):
    Street = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: fake.street_name()) # <-- Lazy load the attribute values
    HouseNumber = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: fake.building_number())
    City = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: fake.city())
    Postcode = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda _: fake.postcode())

    class Meta:
        model = Address


class User(BaseModel):
    Addresses: List[Address]


class UserFactory(factory.Factory):
    Addresses = factory.List([factory.SubFactory(AddressFactory) for _ in range(3)])

    class Meta:
        model = User


user = UserFactory()
user
```

The output:

```
User(Addresses=[Address(Street='Jade rapids', HouseNumber='3', City='Vanessaville', Postcode='B6H 2XA'), Address(Street='Wendy grove', HouseNumber='76', City='West Patricia', Postcode='WR5 0GL'), Address(Street='Smith ramp', HouseNumber='3', City='New Leslie', Postcode='L6 6JF')])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provided, you have to replace `fake.name()` by `Faker("name")`, where `Faker` is imported from `factory` at the beginning of your file.

Indeed, `fake.name()` is called only once, when the class is defined, whereas you want it to happen each time you instantiate a factory.

You'll find a more detailed answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62724145/choosing-from-a-list-of-names-using-factory-boy-integrated-with-faker#answer-62728505).